# save SELECT COUNT into variable using mysql and knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I want to do a count using knex and MySQL and save the count value into a variable. Down below is a snippet of my code. I use postman for requests

```
router.post('/insertNewProject', (req, res) => {
    knex
      .raw('SELECT COUNT(id_proj) FROM project WHERE projectName=?', [req.body.projectName])
      .then((count) => {
        res.json(count[0])
      })
      .catch(() => {
        res.json({ success: false, message: "Please try again later." })
      })
})
```

This will return me:

```
[
    {
        "COUNT(id_proj)": 0  //or 1 of the record is in table
    }
]
```

My question is how can I store the result into a variable? Based on the result of the `select count`, I want if it's `=0` to do a query and if it's greater than 0, to do another query. Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's Easy. You have to access only `count(ip_proj)` value. then you can store in one variable .try this `var result = count[0].COUNT(id_proj);`

Comment: I already tried that, but it's not working. I tried to put it inside `then` but the result will be `Please try again later.`. Where do you sugest to write it?

Comment: okk..!!@Tenzolinho

Comment: read this post maybe it help http://zetcode.com/javascript/knex/

Comment: Following your code - `Please try again later` is in catch-block so it means you have an error in your knex-query

Comment: Your `COUNT(id_proj)` is being used as the javascript variable name, but because of the parentheses it cannot be accessed via javascript dot notation. you can either access it using: `count[0]['COUNT(id_proj)']` or you can change your query to use a different variable name like: `SELECT COUNT(id_proj) AS CNT`. (Although I like do @saka7's query syntax better, as it removes the `raw()` part of the query.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have an error in your knex-query, try this:

```
router.post('/insertNewProject', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await knex('project')
        .count('id_proj as count')
        .where({projectName: req.body.projectName})
        .first()
        .catch(() => res.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Please try again later."
        }));

    if (result.count === 0) {
        // Perform some query
        return res.json({/* Some response */});
    } else {
        // Perform another query
        return res.json({/* Some response */});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this in a different way, getting rid of `select count`:

```
 knex
    .select('*')
    .from('project')
    .where('projectName', '=', req.body.projectName)
    .then((count) => {
      if (count == 0) {
          // do query1
      } else {
          // do query2
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.json({ success: false, message: "Please try again later." })
    })
```

Hope this helps someone.